# Java: Simplest way of sending JSON in Client-server architecture

Tags: java, json, networking, client-server

On a server side I have a config java class that I want to move to JSON and send on client request.

What is on my mind is socket+Jackson but it is pretty low level.

What shall I consider to make it more simple and clean?

Comment: low level is principically a good thing, except if it's complicated to use, which is not the case with socket+jackson. when using annotations jackson should be pretty simple and clean to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe gson can help you. It looks like a high-level library.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but gson is alternative to Jackson so this doesn't bring me much closer to solution.